# Simple vbscript - values not returned from spreadsheet

Tags: vbscript, macros

```
If ActiveSheet.Cells(myRow, 3).Value = "" Then
    APCtext = "" & APC = 2
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(myRow, 3).Value = "?" Then
    APCtext = "Unknown" & APC = 3
Else
    APCtext = ActiveSheet.Cells(myRow, 3).Value & APC = 1
End If
```

The first value this should get is not blank or a question mark, however it doesn't return this value in the else section. Can anyone point out What is wrong with this code?

Comment: i think you are trying to run 2 statements and using the `&` to do so. just make the next statement in new line and use begin end for your statements.

Comment: ah ok whats the normal convention?

Comment: `&` is string concatenation in vbscript.

Comment: Although not very clean (I prefer ericosg answer), you could replace the `&` with `:` and it will also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If ActiveSheet.Cells(myRow, 3).Value = "" Then
    APCtext = ""
    APC = 2
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(myRow, 3).Value = "?" Then
    APCtext = "Unknown"
    APC = 3
Else
    APCtext = ActiveSheet.Cells(myRow, 3).Value
    APC = 1
End If
```